# export from Crystal report XI(cross tab) to excel spreadsheet -- dynmaic columns should not repeat after some rows

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am getting this out from Crystal report XI:

```
NAME          DESCRIPTION      SUBJECT1       SUBJECT2  ....  SUBJECTx      TOTAL    
JACK          CLASS 1           30                              80          110  
AMIT          CLASS 2           50              20                           70  
RAM           CLASS 3           20              30              10           60    
SHYAM         CLASS 4           90              10              10           110
```

But when I try to export the crystal report XI to XLS(excel spreadsheet),the output I get is:

```
    NAME          DESCRIPTION      SUBJECT1       SUBJECT2  ....  SUBJECTx      TOTAL    
    JACK          CLASS 1           30                              80          110  
    AMIT          CLASS 2           50              20                           70  
    RAM           CLASS 3           20              30              10           60    
                                SUBJECT1          SUBJECT2  ....  SUBJECTx      TOTAL  
    SHYAM         CLASS 4           90              10              10           110
```

I don not want column header
**SUBJECT1           SUBJECT2  ....       SUBJECTx          TOTAL**)  to be repeated after some rows,

is there some solution to this, please suggest!!!

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the duplicated headings you have to insert on the column headers on the suppress property X-2 this code:

```
PageNumber > 1
```